# how to reuse elements of an array out of its for loop?

Tags: java

I was trying to create a code that rearranges given elements in an array -by the user- in ascending order, and I have done that, but the program requires
printing the given elements after sorting them firstly, then printing them before sorting.
I have no problem with printing the elements after sorting

the problem is with printing them before sorting
how to re-use `ar[S] = in.nextInt()` the given elements by the user out of its for loop

```java
import java.util.*;

public class SortingnumbersANDswapping {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int swap;  
        int ar[] = new int[3]; //{8,10,5}
        for (int S = 0; S < ar.length; S++) {
            ar[S] = in.nextInt();    //this for loop is used to store numbers in the array

        }
 
 
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            /* this nested for loop is used to compare the first element with the second one in the array
              or the second element with the third.
             */
            for (int j = i + 1; j < ar.length; j++) {
                if (ar[i] > ar[j]) {           //8>10-->F  ,  8>5 -->T ,     {5,10,8}  the new arrangment we are going to use
                    swap = ar[i];             // 10>8-->T               {5,8,10}
                    ar[i] = ar[j];
                    ar[j] = swap;

                }
            }

            System.out.println(ar[i]);  // to print the new order print it inside the array
            
        }
              
        // I wanna do something like that
        // System.out.println(ar[S]);
        // but of course I cant cause array S is only defined in it's loop       
    }

}
```

Comment: `S` is just a variable used to index the array and is not associated with the array at all. You can print the array in a loop similar to what you have: `for (int S = 0; S < ar.length; S++) { System.out.println(ar[S]); }`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i tried that and it reprinted it again after sorting the elements

Comment: If you want to print the original values after sorting, you need to make a [`copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int%5B%5D,int)) the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse it, you need to keep the original array stored in another array that stays untouched. Additionally, Arrays are usually declared as `int[] ar` in Java, instead of `int ar[]`. Something along the following lines should work as intended:

```java
public class SortingnumbersANDswapping {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int swap;
        int[] ar = new int[3]; //{8,10,5}
        for (int S = 0; S < ar.length; S++) {
            ar[S] = in.nextInt();    //this for loop is used to store numbers in the array
        }

        System.out.println("::: Original Array :::");
        int[] originalArray = Arrays.copyOf(ar, ar.length);
        for (int j : originalArray) {
            System.out.println(j);
        }

        System.out.println("::: Sorted Array :::");
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < ar.length; j++) {
                if (ar[i] > ar[j]) {           //8>10-->F  ,  8>5 -->T ,     {5,10,8}  the new arrangment we are going to use
                    swap = ar[i];             // 10>8-->T               {5,8,10}
                    ar[i] = ar[j];
                    ar[j] = swap;

                }
            }
            System.out.println(ar[i]);  // to print the new order print it inside the array
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a copy of the array using the copyOf method from the Arrays library (java.util.Arrays) before you start changing the array.
Here you can find some different approaches - https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/java-copy-array/amp/

Comment: Even if the link can answer, I suggest you to add some example directly in your answer

Comment: I have indeed provided an optional solution, even though I didn't write a specific example, I think it's pretty straightforward to create a new array and just say Arrays.copyOf(initialArr). The link just explains different options, so I don't think your comment is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr));` to print the entire array.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] arr = readArray(3);
    
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < ar.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                swap(arr, i, j);
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr));
            }
        }
    }
}

private static int[] readArray(int size) {
    System.out.format("Enter %d elements:\n", size);
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    
    for(itn i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
    
    return arr;
}

private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```